# Exclude Nulls from ecuation on calculated field of Data Studio

Tags: looker-studio, calculated-field

I have a calculated field in data studio, it's showed in a table.

It calculates the average of a response, based on yes or no:

```js
AVG(CASE 
WHEN EnoughPractice= "Yes" THEN 1
WHEN EnoughPractice= "No" THEN 0
END)
```

My problem is that null values are contemplated on the calculation. For example, if I have in the field EnoughPractice: (null, null, null, yes) it will calculate 25%, but as there is only one answer, it should calculate 100%.

Any help?